# Abstracting operators by booleans

Tags: c

Lets say I have a boolean `bool`, and two ints `a` and `b`. If bool is true, I want to return a < b, and if bool is false I want to return a > b. Obviously I can write:

```
if (bool)
    return a < b;
else
    return a > b;
```

But this is repetitive. I only want to have to write one return statement, of the form `return a (desired operator) b`, but I am not sure what that would look like. What would be the simplest way to do this? Obviously this example is fairly trivial, but for larger blocks of code, I'd prefer to not have to rewrite it multiple times with only the operator changed.

Comment: Don't use `bool` for a variable name.  That's the type name defined by `stdbool.h` for boolean types.

Comment: `return bool ? a < b :a > b;`

Comment: Your example code is confusing. If `b` is a bool, using `<` and `>` operators on it doesn't make sense

Comment: @Spikatrix they say it's an int

Comment: @Shawn Right. But it's still confusing as the same name is used for the boolean and the integer variables

Comment: @Spikatrix `bool`, `a` and `b`?

Comment: Oh, I see. The post was edited to change the names.

Comment: *"What would be the simplest way to do this?"* The simplest way is in your question. What you have is ideal, anything more is taking an extremely simple construct and adding needless complexity.

Comment: That's fair, but, as I said, what if I have 100 lines of computation in each case with only the operator differing by the value of bool? Doesn't seem very efficient then to write out 200 lines of practically duplicated code. This example was kept trivial by intention. Surely there is a way to do this or work around it as I imagine this is a common problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion there's no such operator in C, plus, C doesn't have operator overloading, so that's not possible too.

The best you can do is a function to encapsulate this logic:

```
function findWhetherLessOrMore(bool findWhetherLess, int operand1, int operand2) {
    return findWhetherLess ? operand1 < operand2 : operand1 > operand2;
}
```

You can change the function name to be concise, so that it does not bloat the code when used a large number of times.

As said in other answers here, I would suggest reconsidering your design if you've to do too much of these condition checks in the program.

Answer (score 0):

There are a handful of options, but none of them are *simpler* than just writing directly what you want.

Macros:

```
#define OVERLOADER(cond,a,b,op1,op2) cond ? a op1 b : a op2 b

usage:

return OVERLOADER(cond, a, b, <, >);
```

Virtual functions (which may optimise well when defined static)

```
typedef int(*func)(int a, int b);
static int lt(int a, int b) { return a < b; }
static int gt(int a, int b) { return a > b; }

static int dispatcher(int cond, int a, int b, func aa, func bb) {
    return cond ? aa(a,b) : bb(a,b);
}
// usage:
int main(int ac, char **av) {
    return dispatcher(ac, (int)av[0][0],(int)av[0][1], lt, gt);
}
```

Also if the operator is particularly difficult to evaluate, one might convert the problem into the form

```
if (!cond) {
   swap(a,b);
}
return a < b;
```

The ternary operator will always help in writing conditional statements in a single line and/or having a single return statement.

```
 return cond ? a < b : a > b;
 // or
 return (cond ? a : b) < (cond ? b : a);
```

I would anyway be a bit suspicious of the need to have a block of hundreds of conditions like this, which my intuition tells that should have a better higher level design.